# Get all entries younger than one month and the latest entrie older than one month in a single query with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to get all entries younger than one month and only one entry older than one month with a single query in mongoose. I would need the latest entry older than one month and all younger than one month. My current implementation finds the latest entry older than one month and then in the callback function finds all entries younger than one month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do this in a single query as the queries are mutually exclusive through the non-overlapping date ranges; you want a latest entry older than a month with a query for entries younger than a month which is not possible.

What you can do however is avoid the callback hell by using the [**`async.parallel`**](https://github.com/caolan/async#paralleltasks-callback) utility to run the two queries in parallel. The following example demonstrates this:

```
var monthAgo = new Date();
monthAgo.setMonth(monthAgo.getMonth() - 1);
var older_query = {
        "createdAt": { "$lt": monthAgo }
    },
    younger_query = {
        "createdAt": { "$gte": monthAgo }
    };

async.parallel({
    older: function(callback) {
        Model.findOne(older_query).sort({"createdAt": -1}).exec(function(err, doc) {            
            callback(null, doc);
        });        
    },
    younger: function(callback) {
        Model.find(younger_query).exec(function(err, docs) {            
            callback(null, docs);
        });
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results); // prints for example { older: { createdAt: "date", entry: "foo" }, younger: [{ createdAt: "date", entry: "foo" }, { createdAt: "date", entry: "bar" }, ...]}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This really helps make the code more readable.